# Adding names parameter to numpy genfromtxt causing to read empty strings for data

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I can read the data file fine, but as soon as I try to add the name parameter either by specifying the names myself or reading from the first row I get back empty strings

```
data_no_headers = genfromtxt('SimpleDataWithHeaders.csv',delimiter=',',dtype='str',autostrip=True)
print(data_no_headers)
data_with_headers = genfromtxt('SimpleDataWithHeaders.csv',delimiter=',',dtype='str',autostrip=True,names=True)
print(data_with_headers)
data_with_headers = genfromtxt('SimpleDataWithHeaders.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=1,dtype='str',autostrip=True,names="A,B")
print(data_with_headers)
mycols = ['a','b']
data_with_headers = genfromtxt('SimpleDataWithHeaders.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=1,dtype='str',autostrip=True,names=mycols)
print(data_with_headers)
```

If I execute this code I get the following output (I made a very simple csv file with three rows and a header row to illustrate the problem) you can see the output I get with each of the commands above. You can see it works fine until I add the names parameter

```
[['CODE' 'AIRPORT']
['HOU' 'Houston']
['ABQ' 'Alberquerque']
['BWI' 'Baltimore']]

[('', '') ('', '') ('', '')]

[('', '') ('', '') ('', '')]

[('', '') ('', '') ('', '')]
```

Comment: When using `names`, also specify `dtype=None`.  `dtype=str` makes field dtype 'U', a 0 element string, hence the '' results).  The problem would be more obvious if you looked at `data.dtype` or `print(repr(data))`.

Comment: It you don't need the structured array with fields, you could skip the header, and just get a (n,2) string dtype array.

Comment: Changing dtype=None and adding encoding=None does get the values read in, but now it is no longer creating multiple rows, I get a single row of pairs instead...

Comment: data_with_headers = genfromtxt('SimpleDataWithHeaders.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None, encoding=None,autostrip=True,names=True)
print(data_with_headers)

Comment: [('HOU', 'Houston') ('ABQ', 'Alberquerque') ('BWI', 'Baltimore')]

Comment: That's a 1d structured array.  The pairs are records.  Look at `print(repr(data))`.  If you want a 2d array of strings skip the header.  The header only serves to provide names for the fields of a structured array.

Answer (score 0):

A simulated file:

```
In [243]: txt = """CODE, AIRPORT 
     ...: HOU, Houston 
     ...: ABQ, Alberquerque 
     ...: BWI, Baltimore"""
```

read without using the headers:

```
In [244]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', dtype=str, skip_header=1, 
     ...: encoding=True)                                                                  
In [245]: data                                                                            
Out[245]: 
array([['HOU', ' Houston'],
       ['ABQ', ' Alberquerque'],
       ['BWI', ' Baltimore']], dtype='<U13')
```

The result is a 2d array with a string dtype.

Using the header, and dtype=None:

```
In [246]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, en
     ...: coding=True)                                                                    
In [247]: data                                                                            
Out[247]: 
array([('HOU', ' Houston'), ('ABQ', ' Alberquerque'),
       ('BWI', ' Baltimore')],
      dtype=[('CODE', '<U3'), ('AIRPORT', '<U13')])
In [248]: data.shape                                                                      
Out[248]: (3,)
In [249]: data['CODE']                                                                    
Out[249]: array(['HOU', 'ABQ', 'BWI'], dtype='<U3')
```

The result is a structured array - 1d with 2 fields, which are accessed by name.

With `str` dtype, it is also structured, but the dtype is 'U', a 0 byte string, hence the empty string display:

```
In [250]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',', dtype=str, names=True, enc
     ...: oding=True)                                                                     
In [251]: data                                                                            
Out[251]: 
array([('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '')],
      dtype={'names':['CODE','AIRPORT'], 'formats':['<U','<U'], 'offsets':[0,0], 'itemsize':2})
```

Plain `print` omits the dtype, with possible confusion:

```
In [252]: print(data)                                                                     
[('', '') ('', '') ('', '')]
```